# AjaxForm - is it possible to change defined 'options' during call?

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

```
var options = {
        //target:        '#status',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
        success:       showResponse,  // post-submit callback
        dataType: 'json',
        clearForm: false,
        cache: false,
        type: 'post'
    };

 $('form[name=form1]').submit(function() {
        $('#form1').ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
```

The first form uses the options declared here.

```
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    $('.process').hide();
}
```

These are for the first form. If i use the second form, i want to change the .process class to something else. So, is it possible to append `data:{}` to options during the call? (`ajaxSubmit(options)`) // here can i add additional options? So i can will send form name and class to be hidden.

Comment: like, while the request is processing? once it's sent, it's sent.

Comment: No. i want to change the options here => `ajaxSubmit(options)` - can i append anything here? Like `ajaxSubmit(options + additional options)`

Comment: whats wrong with `options.MyValue = whatIWantItTobe;`?